# Check who makes updates to a Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know I can check sys.tables and see the last modified date for a table.  I am wondering if there is a way to see WHO made the change to the table, based on something like the loginID, the IP user's IP address, or something along those lines?  Is this possible?  I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You'll need to configure some kind of logging (by means of a trigger) or audit when a DDL change occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Enterprise version of SQL Server 2008, then you could use "SQL Server Audit" for this type of information.

Comment: Thanks Landon.  I don't think I have this, but maybe.  I'll check when I'm back in the office tomorrow. morning.